# JQuery interferes with bokeh.js. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bokeh

**TL;DR: my index.html declaration of jQuery with bokeh.js interferes with the ability for the script tags in the php page to manifest themselves into the div that they are supposed to be loaded into. Why?**

I've been trying to embed the output of `graph.create_html_snippet()` from the python bokeh package. I was having so much trouble that I made a separate test html page just to post it to SO, when I discovered that my test page worked! Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/bokeh.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#get_graph").click(function() {
        $("#show_graph").load('hello.php');

    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- click this to bring up graph -->
<a href="#"><div id="get_graph" style="width:100px;height:30px;background-color:#ddd;">Show graph</div></a>

<div id="show_graph"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And hello.php is here:

```
<?php 
echo 'hello';
?>

<script src="31b1ad52-e095-4ba1-89d0-69f0b898d677.embed.js" bokeh_plottype="embeddata" bokeh_modelid="31b1ad52-e095-4ba1-89d0-69f0b898d677" bokeh_modeltype="Plot" async="true"></script>
```

So now, confronted with the mystery of why it wouldn't work on my real page (not posted for brevity) and why it would work on my test page, I started subbing things in and out until I added this to the head of the my test page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
```

And then things stopped working. But then I realized, wait a minute, how did my original test page work in jQuery if I didn't give a script for jQuery in my `<head>`? I went back to my main page and deleted the JQuery script, and suddenly the embeddding worked okay. So I went into the bokeh.js script and found a bunch of calls to jQuery I don't quite understand.

Why is my declaration of jQuery interfering with bokeh.js? When I load the php page using a jQuery declared html page, the html element the php was loaded into will not have the script tags loaded into it, but all other php commands are okay. What's the deal? Since I solved the question while writing this, I guess my question is more out of curiosity/help for people who might run into the same thing, since embedding bokeh using php is one of the best applications for it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recently discovered issue, you can track progress at:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/issues/554

There should be a point release that includes a fix for this very soon.

Comment: Dang, I guess I can't use bokeh after all. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Sorry about that - but please do watch the issue. We're moving pretty fast on development and this issue in particular will definitely be fixed for the next release, which is in a few weeks.

Comment: I actually found a work-around. If you use HTML5 iframes, you can host the bokeh plots in a page with no jQuery. So the main page's code works and the graphs are still embedded.